# How do I fix this materials glitch?

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor

For some reason the blue material has white in it, but it should be fully blue. how can I get rid of the white smudges? I've copied the materials nodes from the body and added it to the armored plate on the chest and just changed the colours and this happened!

*The body of the mesh is supposed to be black

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using some textures? If so may be it's just UV unwrapping problem. Hard to tell without more details.

Comment: Hi :). Looks suspiciously like two overlapping meshes